# File that I recorded with MediaRecorder can't be played

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I'm using MediaRecoder to record sound, but after I'm done recording it can't be played. I tried with Google Play Music, ES Media Player, even uploaded it to pc and tried opening it with Winamp. Nothing plays it!

```
//AUDIO RECORDER
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.reset();       
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    {
        externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        externalOutputPath = externalStoragePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/test.mp3";
        recorder.setOutputFile(externalOutputPath);
    }
    else
    {
        storagePath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(storagePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/test.mp3");
    }
```

Even tried opening it inside the application with button click:

```
public void testPlay (View v) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(externalOutputPath);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

But that crashes the application. But that is not the main problem, the main problem is the fact that there's no way I can play the file. Is there something wrong with encoding or something?

I also tried to change it from .mp3 to .3gp and it didn't work. Then I also tried removing .mp3 and .3gp, leaving just 'test' as a name and then it didn't even recognize it as an audio file.

Oh, and if anyone wants the logcat when the application crashes:

```
07-31 16:51:43.953: E/AndroidRuntime(26918): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-31 16:51:43.953: E/AndroidRuntime(26918): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-31 16:51:43.953: E/AndroidRuntime(26918): Caused by: java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

But again, app crashing isn't the problem at the moment. First I want to solve the problem why the audio file can't be played. But if you have any idea why it crashes I would also appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what was the problem, but I think there was something wrong with the way I stopped recording (the whole try, catch thing). I just rewrote the whole code and put the MediaRecorder in two different methods. startRecording() and stopRecording() method. And now it works perfectly!

startRecording()

```
public void startRecording (){
     recorder = new MediaRecorder();
     recorder.reset();      
     recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
     recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
     recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
     if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
     {
         externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
         externalOutputPath = externalStoragePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/test.mp3";
         recorder.setOutputFile(externalOutputPath);
     }
     else
     {
        storagePath = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        recorder.setOutputFile(storagePath + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/test.mp3");
     }
     recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
     recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

     try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

stopRecording()

```
public void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it for me. I realized that I was missing the release() call on the MediaRecorder instance. Thanks!